# Write down all the non-cyclic groups of the dihedral group of D6.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please help me,I'm still learning group theory and I'm stuck on this one on how to find the non cyclic groups in $D_6$.All I have done first Is that I have listed all the subgroups of D6=$\{1,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,r^5,s,sr,sr^2,sr^3,sr^4,sr^5\}$ having orders
$1$ ,$2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $12$.

$\langle 1\rangle=\{1\}$

$\langle r\rangle=\{1,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,r^5\}$

$\langle r^2\rangle =\{1,r^2,r^4\}$

$\langle r^3\rangle=\{1,r^3\}$

$\langle r^4 \rangle=\{1,r^4,r^2\}$

$\langle r^5\rangle=\{1,r^5,r^4,r^3,r^2,r\}$

$\langle s\rangle=\{1,s\}$

$\langle sr\rangle=\{1,sr\}$

$\langle sr^2 \rangle=\{1,sr^2\}$

$\langle sr^3 \rangle=\{1,sr^3\}$

$\langle sr^4 \rangle=\{1,sr^4\}$

$\langle sr^5 \rangle=\{1,sr^5\}$.

Though I have not shown all the subgroups.Now what is the next step that I have to do to determine whether a subgroup is cyclic or not under this group.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: any subgroup generated by only one element is cyclic; also, it should be noted that some of those you listed are the same, e.g., $\langle r\rangle=\langle r^5\rangle$

Comment: Okay,so should I go the straight way of testing each subgroup if it's generated by any of it's elements to conclude it's non-cyclic or there is a general way?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few hints.  Since $D_6$ has order $12$, you know that a subgroup must have order $1, 2, 3, 4, 6,$ or $12.$  Work your way through that list.  Could a group of order $1$ be noncyclic?  No.
Could a group of order $2$ be noncyclic?  If so, what would it look like?   Continue.

Comment: Can you simply explain to me what makes a subgroup of a dihedral group cyclic then I will have the idea of finding non cyclic subgroups.Does it mean I have to determine whether there's any element in that subgroup that can generate the subgroup

Comment: A group is cyclic if there is one element which generates the whole group when raised to integer powers.  $Z_4$ is cyclic.  $Z_2 \times Z_2$ is not.